# Can I export the results of a duplicate detection job?

Tags: duplicates, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM I'm running a duplicate detection job on *Contact* in order to perform merge operations. I've created a duplicate detection rule as well as a custom view that I use for the detection job, which runs perfectly fine.

After I've merged all the duplicate instances of *Contact* I would like to run a workflow on all the resulting records as well as export the data for the client to see which *Contact*s were affected.

I've noticed that I can run workflows on *Contact* entity as I go by in the duplicate results, but I haven't found a way to select **all of them** and just start the workflow once. And I haven't found any way to get a summary of all the resulting data.